# Distributed Ehcache working using JTA

Tags: ehcache, jta, distributed-transactions, distributed-caching, terracotta

I am trying to do some bench-marking of Distributed transaction memory using Terracotta [Ehcache](http://ehcache.org/) (Open Source). I am having some problem understanding its working with JTA. In code I have found that cache interested in a Distributed Transaction enlist itself as a resource with JTA on which JTA later executes the two phase commit.

My question is if only one cache is enlisted as a resource, how JTA will be able to update all other caches atomically in distributed settings? We are not passing other caches reference to JTA, so atomically update will not be done on them. I feel, I am missing some string here, can anyone explain how it works? I am new to J2EE too, am I missing some J2EE concept which allow automatic reference passing of other caches to JTA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ehcache, if configured that way (`transactionalMode="xa"` or `transactionalMode="xa_strict"`), can work as a full XAResource to participate in JTA transactions (global transactions), which is controlled by a Transaction Manager (from your application server or some standalone product). Ehcache itself takes care of registering at the Transaction Manager in this case. Also, as a full XAResource, multiple caches can be registered and can be part of a transaction.

Strong, cluster-wide consistency is quite expensive (there is no free lunch). It boils down using locks and synchronous (network) operations involving waits, acknowledging etc.

For a more detailed read, I'd suggest you to consult Ehcache docs: [Transactions in Ehcache](http://ehcache.org/documentation/apis/jta)

Comment: As you said: "as a full XAResource, multiple caches can be registered and can be part of a transaction". I have doubt about this registration process. I suppose calling enlistResource( ) makes any resource as part of a transaction. Now when I see the Ehcache code I find at only one resource is enlisted by cache in XAStore when it starts the transaction. It only enlists itself, not other caches which also should be updated atomically. Now my question is by enlisting only one resource how makes this transaction to executive on whole cluster. Is terracotta or JTA doing something internally? what?

Comment: @Codifier: The transaction manager takes care of managing the resources for the transaction. If your cache is a distributed cache (Terracotta clustered cache), then Ehcache/Terracatta (internally) takes responsiblity of making the cache operation to appear as a atomic operation (on the whole cluster). Please see http://ehcache.org/documentation/terracotta/consistency-options#strong-consistency for the details. The one cache that enlists the resource is just one representative of the clustered cache.

Comment: Thanks a lot jeha, that clarifies it. Just one point, If atomicity is already provided by Terracotta, why to use JTA, is it just for transaction recovery?

Comment: @Codifier: In this case, Terracotta is only responsable for the cache itself. In a JTA transaction, handle multiple (XA) resources (database(s), jms, cache, ...) can be involved, which all must be coordinated for a distributed atomic transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Each cache configured with `transactionalMode="xa_strict"` and updated within a JTA transaction will register itself as an XAResource to the transaction manager. This is all automated and transparent to the end user, you don't have anything special at all to do for this mechanism to kick in, you just have to use your cache inside a JTA beg

If you also happen to access other, non-transactional caches in the JTA transaction context, those won't be part of the transaction and will simply be updated as soon as you modify them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply. I am still not clear how it works? I want to understand how automatically it done? If you can direct towards any other resource other than Ehcache.org it will be helpful? Just to repeat how enlisting on resource in transaction, makes whole cluster to update. According to me, one should enlist all the Ehcaches on the cluster in transaction that only should make global transaction.  But in code at XATransactionStore I see only one ehcache being enlisted in transaction. Now how JTA or terracotta register all other clusters to be part of transaction?

Answer (score 0):

Tried xa_strict but there seems to be no automatic enlistment of the XAResource? Switching to plain xa works though...